# Infinite chain of big $O's$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

First, let me write the definition of big $O$ just to make things explicit.

$f(n)\in O(g(n))\iff \exists c, n_0\gt 0$ such that $0\le f(n)\le cg(n), \forall n\ge n_0$

Let's say we have a finite number of functions: $f_1,f_2,\dots f_n$ satisftying:

$O(f_1)\subseteq O(f_2)\dots \subseteq O(f_n)$

By transitivity of $O$, we have that: $O(f_1)\subseteq O(f_n)$

Does this hold if we have an infinite chain of $O's$? In other words, is $O(f_1) \subseteq O(f_\infty)$?

I'm having trouble imagining what's going on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We first need to clarify what we mean by "does this hold if we have an infinite chain?".
We interpret it as an infinite sequence of functions $\{f_i:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} \mid 1\leq i\}$ such that for all $i$ we have $f_i(n) = O(f_{i+1}(n))$. Such a sequence might not have a last function.

We can look at the limit of the functions in the sequence, i.e. $f_\infty(n) = \lim_{i\to \infty} f_i(n)$. However it is possible that the limit does not exists. And even in the case that it exists we might not have $f_1(n) = O(f_\infty(n))$. For example consider the sequence of functions $f_i(n) = \frac{n}{i}$. 
For each $i$, 
$f_i(n)=\Theta(n)$ and therefore $f_i(n) = O(f_{i+1}(n))$.
However $f_\infty(n)=\lim_{i\to\infty}f_i(n)=0=\Theta(1)$
thus $f_1(n) \neq O(f_\infty(n))$.

On the other hand we can look at *the limit of the sequence of the classes* which doesn't need to be equal to *the class of the limit of the functions*.
We have $f_i \in \mathcal O(f_{i+1})$, therefore $\mathcal O(f_i) \subseteq \mathcal O(f_{i+1})$ and $f_j \in \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} \mathcal O(f_i) = \limsup_{i\rightarrow\infty} \mathcal O(f_i) = \liminf_{i\rightarrow\infty} \mathcal O(f_i) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{k>n}\mathcal O(f_k)$ for all $j$. The limit superior contains all elements (functions in this case) which occur infinitely often and the limit inferior contains all elements which occur in all $\mathcal O(f_i), i \ge n_0$ for some $n_0$ (which may depend on the element). Since the sequence of classes is monotonically increasing both exist and they are equal. This justifies the usage of $\lim$.

Comment: There are two series: one of functions (which may converge or not) and one of sets (where each set is a super set of the preceding one; this is why this series converges-see definition of lim inf and lim sup for sets). The first part answers the question without the $f_\infty$ part, the second part answers the $f_\infty$ part negatively (if $f_\infty$ is some sort of limes).

Comment: What if the number of terms is uncountable?  :)

Comment: Using some well-ordering or do you want to replace the series by something more continuous? :)

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks a lot, it makes a lot of sense now. If you could justify the use of limits and what that lim inf thing means, then that will complete my understanding.

Comment: What do you mean by "justify the use of limits"? You asked for a kind of limit ($f_\infty$).

Comment: Can you explain why the limsup and liminf always exist? My understanding was that this argument requires some sort of bounding class, e.g. $\mathbb{O} \supset \mathcal{O(f_i)} (\forall i)$; do we have that here, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes: $\{f|f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\}$ is a bounding class, but the union over all $\mathcal O(f_i)$ should be OK too, because there are only countably many sets.

Comment: @saadtaame, taking the limit is our interpretation of what you meant by $f_\infty$ in the question. I can't think of any other interpretation right now. If you have any other definition then you should specify it in the question.

Comment: @Kaveh I understand that, what's obscure is: I don't see how convergence answers my question? (Am I missing something)

Comment: @saadtaame: Maybe that's because the question above still does not ask what you want to know? If i remember correctly, you added the $f_\infty$ because of a comment suggested it. If you provide some context, maybe someone could rephrase the question again.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to have an infinite chain.

I'm sure you're already familiar with some examples:
$$
 O(x) \subseteq O(x^2) \subseteq \ldots \subseteq O(x^{42}) \subseteq \ldots
$$
You have an infinite chain here: polynomials of growing degree. Can you go further? Sure! An exponential grows faster (asymptotically speaking) than any polynomial.
$$
 O(x) \subseteq O(x^2) \subseteq \ldots \subseteq O(x^{42}) \subseteq \ldots O(e^x)
$$
And of course you can keep going: $O(\mathrm{e}^x) \subseteq O(x\,\mathrm{e}^x) \subseteq O(\mathrm{e}^{2x}) \subseteq O(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x}) \subseteq \ldots$

You can build an infinite chain in the other direction too. If $f = O(g)$ then $\dfrac{1}{g} = O\left(\dfrac{1}{f}\right)$ (sticking to positive functions, since around here we discuss asymptotics of complexity functions). So we have for example:

$$
  O(x) \subseteq O(x^2) \subseteq \ldots
  \subseteq O\left(\dfrac{e^x}{x^2}\right) \subseteq O\left(\dfrac{e^x}{x}\right) \subseteq O(e^x)
$$

In fact, given any chain of functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$, you can build a function $f_\infty$ that grows faster than all of them. (I assume the $f_i$'s are functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}_+$.) First, start with the idea $f_\infty(x) = \max \{f_n(x) \mid n \in\mathbb{N}\}$. That may not work because the set $\{f_n(x) \mid n \in\mathbb{N}\}$ can be unbounded. But since we're only intersted in asymptotic growth, it's enough to start small and grow progressively. Take the maximum over a *finite* number of functions.
$$
f_\infty(x) = \max \{f_n(x) \mid 1 \le n \le N \} \qquad \text{if \(N \le x \lt N+1\)}
$$
Then for any $N$, $f_N \in O(f_\infty)$, since $\forall x \ge N, f_\infty(x) \ge f_N(x)$. If you want a function that grows strictly faster ($f_\infty = o(f_\infty')$), take $f_\infty'(x) = x \cdot (1 + f_\infty(x))$.

Comment: All of this answers (your and other one), is based on assuming that we know what happens in infinity, they are not satisfiable for me, I don't know about the OP (why we shouldn't have closed group with infinite size?)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment: what do you mean by “we know what happens in infinity, they are not satisfiable for me”?